in nextjs 14 how to develop a singleton fontpicker which allows user to select and change font in all pages
in nextjs 14 how to develop a singleton fontpicker so that selected font can be set for all elements below  tag ?
i added nextproject/app/ui/fontpicker.js in nextjs example project but it stops changing font after 4-5 times .
// nextproject/app/ui/fontpicker.js
"use client";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { hin115_font, ing115_font, binaryvertical115_font } from '@/fonts';
const FontPicker = () => {
  const [f, setf] = useState(ing115_font.className);
  document.body.classList.add(f);
  const handlevaluechange = (e) => {
    const v_to_f = (sval) => {
      switch (sval) {
        case '0': return ing115_font.className ;
        case '1': return hin115_font.className ;
        case 'J': return binaryvertical115_font.className ;
        default: return ing115_font.className ;
      }
    }
    const sf = v_to_f(e.target.value);
    setf(sf);     
  };
  return (
    <select onChange={handlevaluechange}>
        <option value="0">iNg115_font</option>
        <option value="1">hin115_font</option>
        <option value="J">binaryvertical115_font</option>
    </select>
  );
};
export default FontPicker;


and using font picker in nextproject/app/ui/acme-logo.tsx as :
import { GlobeAltIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import FontPicker from '@/app/ui/FontPicker';
export default function AcmeLogo() {
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center leading-none text-black" >
          <GlobeAltIcon className="h-12 w-12 rotate-[15deg]" />
          <p className="text-[44px] ">Acme</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center leading-none text-black" >
          <FontPicker />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

